# Renaming file not having proper assigned name

Tags: node.js

I was trying to watch a certain directory and when a new file is added to that directory I want to rename the file but it's not working. The problem is the directory watching part works fine but when I rename the newly added file the name I am giving it is iterated and giving it the wrong name. For Example, if the new name I'm assigning is `thisIsName` when it gets renamed it becomes `thisIsNamethisIsNamethisIsNamethisIsName`. How can I make it so that the rename is the assigned name without any iteration? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const chokidar = require('chokidar');

const watcher = chokidar.watch('filePath', {
  ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../,
  persistent: true
});

function yyyymmdd() {
  var now = new moment();
  return now.format("YYYYMMDD");
}

function hhmmss() {
  var now = new moment();
  return now.format("HHmmss");
}

const log = console.log.bind(console);
//watching a certain directory for any update to it
watcher
  .on('add', path => {
    const newFileName = "filePath\\" + yyyymmdd() + hhmmss() + path
    //trying to rename the file, but its not working because newFileName is somehow getting looped and having multiple iterations of the DATE and TIME in the new name when getting renamed. Example of what the product looks like is included above in the question. 
    fs.renameSync(path, newFileName);
  })
  .on('change', path => {
    log(`File ${path} has been changed`)
  })
  .on('unlink', path => {
    log(`File ${path} has been removed`)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some small changes in your code and it worked for me for any file formats (for unformatted files as well). Anyway, use as you want. The only thing you've missed, was the usage of "path":

```
const moment = require('moment');
const fs = require('fs');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const path = require('path');
const log = console.log.bind(console);

function formattedDate() {
    return moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss');
}

// here I've used some folder with name "folder" in the same directory as this file 
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, `./folder`);
const watcher = chokidar.watch(filePath, {
    ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../,
    persistent: true
});

watcher
    .on('add', addedFilePath => {
        const fileExt = path.extname(addedFilePath);
        const newFilePath = path.join(__dirname, `./folder/${formattedDate()}${fileExt}`);
        fs.renameSync(addedFilePath, newFilePath);
    })
    .on('change', changedFilePath => {
        log(`File ${changedFilePath} has been changed`);
    })
    .on('unlink', removingFilePath => {
        log(`File ${removingFilePath} has been removed`);
    });
```

Here is the stuff:

[image]

Comment: are you sure the name iteration stopped because I replicated it but I'm getting the same results as before

Comment: I've attached a gif, there is a whole process

Comment: oh the iteration is happening because I'm including the ```addedFilePath``` at the end of the ```newFilePath``` string. Do you have any ideas on how I can do the same thing but with ```addedFilePath``` added to the end of```newFilePath```. I.e ```YYYYMMDDHHmmss``` + ```addedFilePath```

Comment: by the way ```addedFilePath``` is a path so I sliced it to get the file name from the path then ```YYYYMMDDHHmmss``` + ```the sliced file name``` but its iterating

Comment: Do you use something like nodemon ?

Comment: yeah I use nodemon

Comment: If you use nodemon or something like that, then for any changes your listener handle all the files inside that folder as the fresh new files, so it executed that again and again. You can try to use with command "node yourFile.js", and then stop and start that, so you can get that iteration again. That is the reason, and you can't operate that. The maximum you can, is that to check the file format (if file starts with "YYYYMMDDHHmmss-") inside the 'add' callback, and if yes then no need to rename the file, else rename the file.

Comment: But this process not a good idea, cuz may you need to restart your server often. So your task itself is not good idea. If the previous solution is that that you want, then go ahead as you want. Else, just think another way for that.
If you want to store something in the file structure, you can save that with some random names, but in the exact folders, like "./YYMMDD/some_generated_random_token.txt"

Comment: So in few words: the reason is nodemon (after stop and start server running the code for all the files inside your folder and renames them again and again)

Comment: Yeah, I was so confused with what was happening. Thanks for the help!